# Does hudson's poll scm support git?

Tags: git, hudson

I configured a job in the hudson to trigger build using "poll scm" method, however, it seems to that it doesn't work.

Does anyone have encounter such problem?
Where could I get relate log on such a issue?

Can anyone tell me how could I diagnose this problem?

Comment: it would be useful to add details about how and why it doesn't work

Comment: I wonder how and why too, So I want to know how to locate the hudson's log file(not the job's log)

Comment: There is a "Git polling log" link in the sidebar on each job's page, if I recall right

Answer (score 3):

When viewing a job, there is a "Git Polling Log" link is in the sidebar:

[image: Git Polling Log in Jenkins]

This often shows useful errors if something has gone wrong (or indicates if the polling is not happening as regularly as you expect - check the timestamps)

A "everything went okay" log looks something like this:

```
Started on Jun 20, 2012 10:11:27 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Build : #1
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision c5d36c91be40b9dbeed44d6649a3535ad0a524ac (origin/master)
Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories
Fetching upstream changes from https://example/repo.git
Polling for changes in
Done. Took 1.2 sec
No changes
```

Comment: I can not see the "Git Polling Log" link in the sidebar. Can you upload a picture please?
The only clue is the job's log which looks like the following when I use "periodically approach"
Started by timer
Checkout:workspace .....
Using strategy: Default

But if I use SCM Poll, the job log won't be generated.

Comment: @welkinwalker Screenshot added. Was taken in Jenkins, but I'm almost certain the log-page was there long before the branching from Hudson

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a schedule in order for it to work.
For example I'm using

```
* * * * *
```

this way the build is started when I push a new commit to the branch

[image]

Comment: yes, I did all these.  provide the git repository, and set build triggers to poll SCM, and write a contab expression "25 * * * *", and do the commit at 23 minute just before the poll time.However, I did not work

Comment: If I select the build periodically, I worked fine. So I suspect whether it support git when using Poll SCM.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are pending (or closed "not repro") bug for a not working "Poll SCM" option:

- Hudson: "[5677: git scm does not detect changes on master branch of upstream repo](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5677)"
- Jenkins: "[5677: git scm does not detect changes on master branch of upstream repo](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5677)"

The comments vary slightly between the two, with the following clue:

> I have fixed the problem; it seems that when the plugin tries to call "`git tag -l master`", it will exit with a non-zero status if there are no tags on git version 1.5.2.5
>
> I have since upgraded our version of git to 1.7.5-rc1, and it no longer fails when there are no tags named master.
>
> Perhaps the exit status of "`git tag -l master`" shouldn't be checked, or a specific git version should be enforced (is it in the doc? I'm sorry to say I haven't read them...)

Comment: The CI server I use is hudson, I have seen this post before I ask the question here, it seems that the problem was solved one year ago, and could not be reproduce with ver2.0.1, but my version is 2.2.0(both hudson and git plugin)